# How to implement an Oracle AQ queue in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, jms, oracle-aq, advanced-queuing

I already found out how to create an Oracle database with AQ (Streams?) packages. I also created some queue's in Oracle (by hand). (Using PL/SQL and SQL).

However, I'm having a hard time setting up a proper connection from Spring.

The following works (using `oracle.AQ` java package):

```
private final String aqUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
private final String aqUser = "queue_mut";
private final String aqPassword = "******";
private final String aqSchema = "queue_mut";
private final String aqTable = "aq_table1";
private final String aqQueue = "aq_queue1";


@Test
public void testManualAQ() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, AQException {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(aqUrl, aqUser, aqPassword);
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    Class.forName("oracle.AQ.AQOracleDriver");
    AQSession aqSession = AQDriverManager.createAQSession(connection);
    AQQueueTable q_table = aqSession.createQueueTable(aqSchema, aqTable, new AQQueueTableProperty("RAW"));
    aqSession.createQueue(q_table, aqQueue, new AQQueueProperty());

}
```

(based on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/apexampl.htm)

This shows me that I can connect to Oracle and reach AQ functionality.

Now, I'm trying to create Java Configured beans in order to use the `JmsTemplate`.

```
@Resource
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Test
public void testJmsTemplate() {
    String xmlval = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<product id=\"10\">\n" +
            " <description>Foo</description>\n" +
            " <price>2.05</price>\n" +
            "</product>";

    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(aqSchema + ".jms_ws_incoming_queue", xmlval);
}
```

(yes, the queue already exists ;-))

With the following configuration class:

```
import oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class OracleAQConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager manager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws JMSException {
        return AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
}
```

And with properties yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
    username: queue_mut
    password: ******
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

But with this I get errors which I cannot grasp:

```
2017-04-19 12:11:17,151  INFO my.project.QueueTest: Started QueueTest in 5.305 seconds (JVM running for 6.588)

org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is oracle.jms.AQjmsException: Error creating the db_connection; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection

    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:658)
    at my.project.QueueTest.testJmsTemplate(QueueTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: oracle.jms.AQjmsException: Error creating the db_connection
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsDBConnMgr.getConnection(AQjmsDBConnMgr.java:625)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsDBConnMgr.<init>(AQjmsDBConnMgr.java:399)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnection.<init>(AQjmsConnection.java:249)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnectionFactory.createConnection(AQjmsConnectionFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsGeneralDBConnection.getProviderKey(AQjmsGeneralDBConnection.java:98)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsGeneralDBConnection.<init>(AQjmsGeneralDBConnection.java:67)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsDBConnMgr.getConnection(AQjmsDBConnMgr.java:566)
    ... 41 more
```

I believe that the Cast exception occurs because it is a `ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@40016ce1]]`. But I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Change the `jdbc` library, in my case this fixed it(if don't, try with some other versions):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

We experienced the same exception when tried to access Oracle AQ from Spring boot. Research indicated that this exception is thrown as the Database connection pool libraries doesn't allow the access  to the underlying connection required by the oracle AQ Library.(Both dbcp and tomcat connection pool libraries threw  exceptions , not same but similar)

This exception was gone when we removed the Database connection pool libraries from dependencies which lead to an undesirable state of having no Database connection pooling for the entire application .

We noticed that the if we use the  following method  the exception is not thrown
`AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(url, info);`

Perhaps connection pooling is missing with solution also, but that is limited to the component which reads from AQ . Other components in the app will have the benefits of the connection pooling

Here is the java config for the Bean definition:

```
@Bean
public QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws Exception {
    OracleServiceInfo serviceInfo = (OracleServiceInfo) this.cloud().getServiceInfo(NAME_PRIMARY_DS);
    Properties info = new Properties();
    String url = serviceInfo.getJdbcUrl();
    info.put("driver-name", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    info.put("user", serviceInfo.getUserName());
    info.put("password", serviceInfo.getPassword());
    return oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(url, info);
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws Exception {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

I am not sure yet if this a good solution. But this is definitely one  way to get rid of the exception discussed in the question.

Comment: what is that part of `this.cloud`?

Comment: this sample is from a spring boot project which gets the connection details from a  service binding in pivotal cloud foundry

Answer (score 1):

Hi it also took me quite some time to make the connection work, but finally it did and this is how:

First make sure the payload of your Oracle AQ Queue table is not set to RAW but preferably to Text: SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE

Next use a OracleAQConfiguration similar as hereunder:

```
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Configuration
public class OracleAQConfiguration {

    // Values are retrieved from custom added props in Spring application.properties

    @Value("${myapplication.datasource.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${myapplication.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${myapplication.datasource.connectionstring}")
    private String connectionstring;

    @Bean
    /**
     * Spring bean with the configuration details of where the Oracle database is containing the QUEUES
     */
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
        ds.setUser(user);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        ds.setURL(connectionstring);
        ds.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        ds.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    /**
     * The KEY component effectively connecting to the Oracle AQ system using the datasource input
     */
    public QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws JMSException {
        return AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(dataSource);
    }

}
```

Next use a JMSConfiguration similar as hereunder.
Here I read and write to the same queue which is unlikely in a real application integration scenario. But OK for testing

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class JMSConfiguration {
    private static final String QUEUENAME_WRITE = "MYQUEUE";
    private static final String QUEUENAME_READ = "MYQUEUE";

    @Autowired
    private JMSReceiver jmsReceiver;

    @Bean
    /**
     * Spring bean to WRITE/SEND/ENQUEUE messages on a queue with a certain name
     */
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory conFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(QUEUENAME_WRITE);
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(conFactory);

        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Spring bean to READ/RECEIVE/DEQUEUE messages of a queue with a certain name
     * All of this happens under a code managed transaction
     * to commit the change on Oracle (remove of the message from the queue table)
     * Reference the application custom code handling the message here
     */
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory conFactory, DataSource dataSource) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        dmlc.setDestinationName(QUEUENAME_READ);
        dmlc.setSessionTransacted(true);
        dmlc.setConnectionFactory(conFactory);

        DataSourceTransactionManager manager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dmlc.setTransactionManager(manager);

        // Add here our self-written JMS Receiver
        dmlc.setMessageListener(jmsReceiver);
        return dmlc;
    }

}
```

Finally for handling incoming JMS messages use something like:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.SessionAwareMessageListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

@Component
public class JMSReceiver implements SessionAwareMessageListener {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSReceiver.class);

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
        // We know/assume the Queue Payload type was set to 'TextMessage'
        TextMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        logger.info("JMS Text Message received: " + txtMessage.getText());

        // ... further implementation
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the AQ code expected an OracleConnection but when pooled the connection wrapped and hence it fails

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Bean
    public AQjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) throws Exception{
        AQjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new AQjmsConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setDatasource(dataSource);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(@Autowired AQjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Exception{
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate=new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

POM File:

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.messaging</groupId>
            <artifactId>aqapi-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>23.2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.transaction/jakarta.transaction-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

//Code to send message to Oracle AQ JMS Queue using Spring JMS Template

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.jms.JMSException;
import jakarta.jms.Message;
import jakarta.jms.Session;

@Service
public class JmsUtil {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    //Send JMS message to Oracle AQ JMS queue
    public void sendMessageToJmsQueue(YourPojoClass yourPojoClass) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
            String pojoAsJson=mapper.writeValueAsString(yourPojoClass);
            jmsTemplate.send("YourQueueName", new MessageCreator() {
                public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException{
                    return session.createTextMessage(pojoAsJson);
                }
            });
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```